# PHPExcel sheet some of last columns cutoff into another page

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm using PHPEXcel to write the data.Excel sheets are generated properly but the problem is when I'm trying to print all the pages but split into two pages means half of the page is print in one sheet and another half is printing into another sheet.I need to print the sheet should same as the excel which i have.

Can any one suggest me how to make my excel sheet to print single with column cutoff?

Like this is my sample code.

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCElls('A1:H5');
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCElls('A6:A37');

            $sheet->getSheetView()->setZoomScale(300);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                   ->getColumnDimension( 'B' )->setWidth('6');
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                   ->getColumnDimension( 'C' )->setWidth('6');
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                   ->getColumnDimension( 'D' )->setWidth('11');

            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                   ->getColumnDimension( 'E' )->setWidth('30');
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                   ->getColumnDimension( 'F' )->setWidth('14');
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                   ->getColumnDimension( 'G' )->setWidth('18');
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                   ->getColumnDimension( 'H' )->setWidth('25');
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                   ->getRowDimension( '6' )->setRowHeight('39.36');
            $sheet->setCellValue('F6','Invoice');
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('F6')->applyFromArray($font_style);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('F6')->applyFromArray($hstyle);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells("F6:H6");
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B6:H6')->applyFromArray($Border_Style);

            $sheet->setCellValue('B8',$invoice_info['site_name']);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells("B8:E8");
            $sheet->setCellValue('B9',$invoice_info['address1']);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells("B9:E9");
            $sheet->setCellValue('B10',$invoice_info['address2']);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells("B10:E10");
            $sheet->setCellValue('B11',$invoice_info['address3']);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells("B11:E11");
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B10:E11')
                        ->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true); 
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B7:E11')->applyFromArray($BStyle);
```

Comment: can you please share your code?

Comment: I have edited my question. please refer.